# Is it legal for UK Tier 2 General migrant to have extra income by means of online services like Udemy?

Tags: united-kingdom, working-visas, employment

I am currently in the UK on a tier 2 general visa. This visa prevents you from undertaking a second employment unless you satisfy some rules. But the policy guideline does not say clearly whether such people are allowed to have extra income through other means which are not same as a second employment e.g. selling courses on Udemy.

Does anyone have any experience in this area?

Comment: I have experience in T2.  The rules are vague on this particular question.  You need to put it to the policy unit in Sheffield and get a reading on it.  Hence close voting this as opinion-based at the moment since it needs a reading.

Comment: When you get a reply from Sheffield, you can come back and reopen your question and put the answer in. It may help some other T2's.